# Average color of multiple images merged together

Tags: python, arrays, image

I have all these layers in Photoshop:
[image: Layers in Photoshop]

I also have these images in Python. In Photoshop, I can get the average color of the entire document from the RGB channel of the document. In Python, I was thinking I would blend the images together using cv2.addWeighted, and then use the histograms of the three channels to get the average color. However, my average color does not match with the one obtained from Photoshop.

Here is my code so far:

```
    im1 = cv2.imread('a1.png')
    im2 = cv2.imread('a2.png')
    im3 = cv2.imread('a3.png')
    alpha = 0.5
    beta = (1.0 - alpha)
    blended = cv2.addWeighted(im1, alpha, im2, beta, 0.0)
    blended = cv2.addWeighted(blended, alpha, im3, beta, 0.0)
    # cv2.imwrite('blended.png', blended)
    averageColor = []

    chans = cv2.split(blended)
    colors = ("b", "g", "r")
    for (chan, color) in zip(chans, colors):
        # create a histogram for the current channel and plot it
        hist = cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
        for i in range(len(hist)):
            if (hist[i]) != 0:
                averageColor.append(i)
                break

    print("Average color: ", averageColor)
    base_color = np.fill((aw, ah, 3), averageColor)
    base_color_layer = Image.fromarray(base_color)
    base_color_layer.save("Base Color.png")
```

im3 is the "dup" layer containing only one color (129, 127, 121). im2 is all the Mask layers summed together using np.add. im1 is the Background image.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Here you picked `alpha = 0.5`, and do the blending in 2 steps, which results in something like `0.25*im1+0.25*im2+0.5*im3`. It's hard to tell from the screenshot what settings and operations you have in PS, but obviously there are a number of things which can go mismatching.

Comment: Yes that looks to be wrong. How can I balance the weights? In the second blending, should I give 0.75 weight to the first image and 0.25 to the second?

Comment: `0.5-0.5` is okay for the first pair, but then `0.67-0.33` should be used for the pair-im3 step. Then they will end up with ~0.33-ish weight individually.

Comment: just sum all the images, and afterwards divide by the number of images...

Answer (score 0):

```py
# given
im1 = cv2.imread('a1.png')
im2 = cv2.imread('a2.png')
im3 = cv2.imread('a3.png')

# calculations
averageIm = np.mean([im1, im2, im3], axis=0)
averageColor = averageIm.mean(axis=(0,1))
```

Assuming the images are color without alpha, and assuming you want each picture to have equal weight.

This is ***not equivalent*** to a stack of layers and giving each layer the same transparency, because that is equivalent to exponential/geometric average, i.e. `alpha * im1 + (1-alpha) * (alpha * im2 + (1-alpha) * (im3))` which gives an image successively less weight the lower it is on the stack. it goes like `[0.5, 0.25, 0.25]`, or `[0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, ...]`

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I would highly recommend you do this with the CUDA API (either in C or with the Python bindings) but since the qn is about pure python, see below

I'm not going to add all the cv2 reading code bc idk the API but let's assume you've got images 1...n in a list called `images` and each image is a 3d array of width x height x rgba and let's assume all images are the same size

```py
Image_t = list[list[list[int]]]

def get_average_colour(images: list[Image_t]) -> Image_t:
    new_image: Image_t = []
    image_width = len(images[0][0])  # len of first row in first image
    image_height = len(images[0])  # number of rows
    colour_channel_size = len(images[0][0][0]) 

    for h in range(image_height):
        row = []
        for w in range(image_width):
            curr_pixel = [0] * colour_channel_size
            for img in images:
                for chan, val in enumerate(img[h][w]):
                    curr_pixel[chan] += val
                row.append(list(map(lambda v: int(v / len(images), curr_pixel))  # This will average out your pixel values
        new_image.append(row)

    return new_image
```

Comment: What if the images are RGB instead of RGBA? Because that's what they are.

Comment: in that case just dont hardcode curr_pixel like me and get the channel size with len(images[0][0][0]), I will update my answer to make this more dynamic

Comment: I want to reaaaaally stress that the operation you're trying to perform will be thousands or millions of times faster with GPU operations. If this code is intended to run on a machine with an NVidia GPU which supports CUDA, I HIGHLY recommend using their python wrapper lib:
https://nvidia.github.io/cuda-python/overview.html
https://nvidia.github.io/cuda-python/api.html

This will allow you to run the pixel ops in parallel instead of wasting cycles upon cycles of iteration. There are many examples online about Matrix-Matrix multiplication with CUDA

Comment: @zkscpqm you could have just used numpy. no need at all for cuda here. CPUs are fast enough to add a few pictures... and numpy routines are faster than plain python loops.